# mysql replication: one master with lots of databases, two slaves - one for all DB's and one - only for one of DBs

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a production mysql server. And one server for backups, with mysql slave running on it. As development continues I want to setup a small development server replicating only one of databases from master, ignoring binlogs for all other databases existing on master. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and it easy. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-rules.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should be aware that always the full binlog for all databases is sent to all slaves. This can be important if you have large databases and want to replicate over a slow network connection. The transfered data will be the same regardless of the size of the specific database you want to keep.